# Openvpn configuration problem - cannot ping the vpn server with it's usual IP address

Tags: openvpn

I'm a total VPN noob setting up my first openvpn on a centos VM in my office which has a LAN in the 192.168.0.x network. I've successfully configured my laptop to connect from home - it gets assigned an IP address of 10.10.10.6. I think the server is getting 10.10.10.1 and when I ping it it responds. However when I ping the server on its noraml IP address (192.168.0.108) i get nothing.

Here is the server.conf file:

```
local 0.0.0.0   
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh dh1024.pem
server 10.10.10.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 10.0.3.0 255.255.255.0"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
user openvpn
group openvpn
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 4
```

This is the VPN section of my server's ifconfig:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:10.10.10.1  P-t-P:10.10.10.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:22 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:100
          RX bytes:1234 (1.2 KiB)  TX bytes:1158 (1.1 KiB)
```

Here is my laptop's ipconfig:

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::c054:233e:21f1:ac42%14
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.6
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wireless Network Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::b98a:8bd5:6739:1e54%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.2
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{BF535BB4-4351-4B88-8ED1-17613C04282F}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter isatap.{06736C0E-354E-4806-AA58-BDA90A1B4EDC}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 9:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 2001:0:5ef5:79fd:38e6:357c:3f57:fefd
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::38e6:357c:3f57:fefd%16
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : ::
```

Here is the output of route print on my win7 laptop

```
C:\Users\BenLaptop7>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 14...00 ff 06 73 6c 0e ......TAP-Win32 Adapter V9
 12...00 21 6a 27 a7 fa ......Intel(R)  WiFi Link 5300 AGN
 11...00 21 70 d9 6e bb ......Intel(R) 82567LM Gigabit Network Connection
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 17...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
 15...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #3
 16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1      192.168.1.2     25
         10.0.3.0    255.255.255.0       10.10.10.5       10.10.10.6     30
       10.10.10.1  255.255.255.255       10.10.10.5       10.10.10.6     30
       10.10.10.4  255.255.255.252         On-link        10.10.10.6    286
       10.10.10.6  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.6    286
       10.10.10.7  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.6    286
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
      192.168.1.2  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link        10.10.10.6    286
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link        10.10.10.6    286
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.2    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

... which I don't really understand but when I first got it working I was able to connect to my server (which has a couple of Samba shares) from Windows by typing \10.10.10.1 however that has recently stopped working since I rebooted the server having set the default runlevel to 5 to that I can set up a VNC client to use the VPN.

Does anyone know how I can a) get this working again and b) make it so that my server can be reached over the VPN by its usual IP address (192.168.0.108)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure you have to push all the subnets you want to allow, had this setup a while ago.

http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html

```
First, you must advertise the 10.66.0.0/24 subnet to VPN clients as being accessible through the VPN. This can easily be done with the following server-side config file directive:

    push "route 10.66.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Otherwise the routes are locked down, the openvpn server is trying to keep your internal network safe.  So unless you advertise the routes, the clients won't be allowed to see them.

So you'd want to do this in your server config...

```
push "route 10.0.3.0 255.255.255.0"
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
```

Comment: Happy to help.  :)